# java generic: declaration of recursive types

Tags: java, generics

In *Effevtive Java* I see a declaration: `public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(List<T> list)`, type variable `T` is a type can be compared to itself. My question is what's the difference when I remove `<T>` from `Comparable` ? I mean this `public static <T extends Comparable> T max(List<T> list)` .

Comment: It means you're using a raw type, and raw types are always evil.

Answer (score 4):

That means that you will then expect a type that is comparable to `Object`, since java infers generic types to be `Object` when not provided.

```
<T extends Comparable> // The generic type for Comparable is inferred as Object as it was not provided.
```

This means that the type provided to the list would need to implement `compareTo(Object o)` and implement `Comparable` (notice the missing generic type to `Comparable`), which I assume is not intended.

Comment: Then I specify a List of String for the `max` method, but `String` implements `compareTo(String anotherString)` not `compareTo(Object o)`.

Comment: @user2018791 Providing a `List<String>` will work when you use `<T extends Comparable<T>>` will work as `String` implements `Comparable<String>`

Comment: But `static <T extends Comparable> T max(List<T> list)` is working fine when I provide `List<String>` even `String` implements `compareTo(String)` not `compareTo(Object)`

Answer (score 3):

You would have your parametrized type declared to implement the `Comparable` interface in a "raw" way.

For instance, a `class Foo implements Comparable` (raw type) would fit your parametrized type.

In turn, that class could override `compareTo(Object o)` instead of `compareTo(Foo f)`.