# "class A <T extends SomeClass<T>>" works differently from class B <T extends SomeInterface<T>> ? (Yes)

Tags: java, generics

While the definition involving interface Comparable

```
class B <T extends Comparable<T>>
```

is well known and instantiable, the same usage does not work in the same manner when extending a class instead of an interface.  Here's an example

```
class G <T extends Box<T>> {
    T val;
    G(T val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

The above class compiles, but I am unable to find a way to instantiate G. It seems to require an infinite nesting of Box.

```
G<Box<Box<..>>>
```

Here is my definition of class Box

```
class Box <T> {
    T val;
    Box(T val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

To aid in discussion, here are a few similar examples. I tested all of my code.

The meaning of the following class is clear to me

```
class D <T extends Box<String>> {
    T val;
    D(T val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

we can instantiate using

```
    D<Box<String>> d = new D<>( new Box<String> ("hello") );
```

We can generalize this so that the Box can contain anything

```
class F <S, T extends Box<S>> {
    T val;
    F(T val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

we can instantiate using

```
    F<String,Box<String>> f = new F<>( new Box<String> ("hello") );
```

Back to the original question, what does the following mean and how/can it be instantiated?

```
class G <T extends Box<T>> {
    T val;
    G(T val) {
        this.val = val;
    }
}
```

This class G was my first attempt to generalize the class D above so that Box can hold any type, not just String.  I later came up with class F as the solution to my problem, but I am left wondering what does G mean and why is it different from when `T extends SomeInterface<T>`.

Comment: If `T` is a subclass of `Box<T>`, that means that `Box<T>` must have existed before `T` did, which intuitively seems impossible (even though `T` is just a placeholder for any class). Have you seen this somewhere or is this hypothetical?

Comment: @Gendarme  This is just a hypothetical question.

Comment: Actually, it seems like [this is possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39327662/java-generic-declaration-of-recursive-types) (at least when `A` is an interface).

Comment: It's possible for classes as well. In fact, [enum does this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html).

Comment: The later generalization `class F<S, T extends Box<S>>` is not really meaningful. It woild be if you introduced some type bound, e.g. `class F<S extends Comparable<S>, T extends Box<S>>`. This would let you use abstract comparison on `S`.

Comment: `@Some Name` why do you say F is not meaningful? It generalizes D so that Box can hold any class, not just String.

Comment: `@TiiJ7` any thoughts on if it is possible to instantiate the case where the class is not Enum? Enum has special compiler support.

Comment: `@Gendarme` Using the comments and answers received, I wrote and tested examples and posted a synopsis in an answer below.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `Box` class doesn't have constructor with `T`, then you can create a class that extends `Box`. For example:

```
class NewBox extends Box<NewBox> {
    ...
}
```

Then you can instantiate `G` like:

```
G<NewBox> g = new G<>(new NewBox());
```

But in your case Box has constructor `Box(T val){...}`, then `NewBox` required constructor matching `super` like:

```
class NewBox extends Box<NewBox> {
    NewBox(NewBox val) {
        super(val);
    }
}
```

To instantiate this you should end up with null, otherwise it will lead to infinite nesting :

```
G<NewBox> g = new G<>(new NewBox(new NewBox(new NewBox(null))));
```

**Update:** to answer your original question: `G <T extends Box<T>>` means that `T` must be type of `Box` or any descendant of `Box`. As you correctly mentioned it will lead to infinite nesting. But you still can instantiate this *without creating extra class* (as above with `NewBox`) using [Wildcard](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) and `null` as a parameter to the constructor of class `G` like:

```
G<?> tg = new G<>(null);
```

Comment: @RFS updated with one more example address original question

Comment: `@Ruslan`  I tried it out.  Works as intended. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you are concerned about the type bound `T extends Box<T>` means the only types that can be specified as type parameter has to extend `Box`.

This technique is used to specify additional operations you can do with your type (e.g. well known `Comparable<T>`) so this is not really common to use class rather then interface.

Let me give you some example. Say we have the following operations

```
interface Op1<T>{
    void doOp1(t: T): T
}

interface Op2<T> {
   void doOp2(t: T): T
}

class MyClass implements Op1<MyClass>, Op2<MyClass>{
    //By implementing Op1 and Op2 you
    //specify that operations doOp1 and doOp2
    // can be applied to variable of typr MyClass
}
```

And now you you want to implement your generic container which accepts elements of types the `Op1` and `Op2` can be applied to

```
class MyContainer<T extends Op1<T> & Op2<T>>{
   //you can apply doOp1 and doOp2 to any variable of the type T
}

MyContainer<MyClass> t = //... Ok
MyContainer<Integer> t = //... Not ok
```

In functional programming similar (but not really same) thing is called typeclasses

Comment: But this doesn't answer my original question of how to instantiate G <T extends Box<T>> where Box is a class, and what <T extends Box<T>> means when Box is a class.

Comment: @RFS You cannot instantiate `G` using the `Box` itself. Like you noticed it would require infinite reqursion. You need to subclass it as `Mcls extends Box<Mcls>` (e.g `Integet implements Comparable<Integer>`)

Comment: @RFS As to what it means when `Box` is a class. I cannot imagine any common use case. You would better of describing your intention to use class. When it is a class it inhibts usage of combined type bound, e.g. `class Tox<T>{ }`. And you cannot add an additional bound as `class G<T extends Box<T> & Tox<T>>` is not possible. When it is an `interface` as I said it means an additional  operation on a type `T`: `class G<T extends Comparable<T> & Op1<T> & Op2<T>>`

Answer (score 0):

## ANSWER SYNOPSIS

Drawing from the answers of `@Ruslan` and `@Some Name` and comments on the question, here is a synopsis of the differences between

```
class G <T extends SomeClass<T>>
class B <T extends SomeInterface<T>>  
class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>
```

I found that writing tested examples helps.

### 1. `class G <T extends SomeClass<T>>`

Class `G` requires type `T` to be defined like

```
class T extends SomeClass<T> {}
```

Here is an example of a class like `T`

```
class RussianBox extends Box<RussianBox> {
    RussianBox(RussianBox box) {
        super(box);
    }
}
```

where class `Box` is defined as

```
class Box <T> {
    T value; 
    Box(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName()+" containing {"+this.value+"}";
    }
}
```

Here is an example of a class like `G`

```
class RussianBoxContainer <T extends Box<T>>   {
    T value; 
    RussianBoxContainer(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName()+" containing {"+this.value+"}";
    }
}
```

The following code instantiates these three classes

```
    Box<String> box = new Box<>("Gold");
    out.println("box = " + box );

    RussianBox russianBox = new RussianBox( new RussianBox(null) );
    out.println("russianBox = " + russianBox );

    RussianBoxContainer<RussianBox> containerForARussianBox = new RussianBoxContainer<>(russianBox);
    out.println("containerForARussianBox = " + containerForARussianBox );
```

and produces the following output

```
box = Box containing {Gold}
russianBox = RussianBox containing {RussianBox containing {null}}
containerForARussianBox = RussianBoxContainer containing {RussianBox containing {RussianBox containing {null}}}
```

### 2. `class B <T extends SomeInterface<T>>`

Class `B` requires type `T` to be defined like

```
class T extends SomeClass implements SomeInterface<T> {}
```

The `java.lang.Integer` class is an example of a class like `T`

```
class Integer extends Number implements Comparable<Integer>
```

Thus, this pattern behaves very differently when referring to an interface instead of a class.

### 3. `class Enum<E extends Enum<E>>`

Now to create a class *like* `Enum`.  Here is an example

```
class RussianBoxContainer2 <T extends RussianBoxContainer2<T>>   {
    RussianBoxContainer2<T> value; 
    RussianBoxContainer2(RussianBoxContainer2<T> box) {
        this.value = box;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName()+" containing {"+this.value+"}";
    }
}
```

Just like `Enum`, we need to subclass `RussianBoxContainer2` before we can use `RussianBoxContainer2`.  Here is an example of a subclass

```
class RussianBox2 extends RussianBoxContainer2<RussianBox2> {
    RussianBox2(RussianBox2 box) {
        super(box);
    }
}
```

The following code instantiates these two classes

```
RussianBox2 russianBox2 = new RussianBox2(new RussianBox2(null));
out.println("russianBox2 = " + russianBox2 );

RussianBoxContainer2<RussianBox2> containerForARussianBox2 = new RussianBoxContainer2<>(russianBox2);
out.println("containerForARussianBox2 = " + containerForARussianBox2 );
```

and produces the following output

```
russianBox2 = RussianBox2 containing {RussianBox2 containing {null}}
containerForARussianBox2 = RussianBoxContainer2 containing {RussianBox2 containing {RussianBox2 containing {null}}}
```